# Magento2 - Wordpress5.2.4 installation issue

Tags: magento-2.2.5, wordpress, post

I am using a magento 2.2.5 site. I have installed WordPress in a sub directory of my root directory. I have integrated the WordPress 5.2.4 in magento site by using fishpig WordPress extension. All other things are working fine. Now I got all my WordPress post in this url **`www.example.com/blog`**

The issue is i tried saving post in WordPress admin but it reflects error as below
**`api-fetch.min.js?ver=3.1.2:1`** **POST** **`hwww.example.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/6978?_locale=user`** 404 (Not Found).

How can I do it? When ?

I tried the permalinks extension in WordPress,but still the issue exist.

Comment: Try saving permalinks in admin general settings. Also i feel its .htacccess permission issue by Magento. you need to do some tweak with this.

Comment: Tried saving permalinks but not working Can u provide detail regarding .htaccess file how to provide permission

Answer (score 1):

Install wp-cli in your wordpress site

- curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
- chmod +x wp-cli.phar
- sudo mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp

Update the url in this way :

```
wp option update home https://yoursitename.com/blog/
wp option update siteurl https://yoursitename.com/wp/

wp cache flush
wp option get siteurl
wp option get home
```

- Check if you have any iframe integrated in your post.
- Try to remove the iframe and save the post again.  If you want the iframe , you should give permissions on firewall .

Comment: I had no idea about this tool. Great tip!